# Merge two lists in python issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have two lists in python

Names:

```
['Test 1', 'Test 2']
```

isTrue:

```
[False, True]
```

I want to merge the lists into one list and the result being:

```
[{name: 'Test 1', isTrue: False}, {name: 'Test 2', isTrue: True}]
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
list = []
thisdict = {}
for name in names:
    thisdict['name'] = name
    thisdict['isTrue'] = True
    list.append(thisdict)
```

The issue is I am not sure how to get the dynamic boolean value or how to do this a lot more effeciently.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and `zip`:

```
>>> [dict(name=x, isTrue=y) for x, y in zip(names, isTrue)]
```

Comment: What does zip do?

Comment: @HeelMega It *"returns an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables."*. Please consider [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

small modification required in your code.

```
list = []
list_iteration = 0
for name in names:
    thisdict = {'name':name , 'isTrue':isTrue[list_iteration] }
    list.append(thisdict)
    list_iteration+=1
```